# Scalar curvature calculating problem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I have a problem understanding calculating Ricci and scalar curvature.

By definition: for every $p \in M$ and $x,y \in T_pM$ with respect to any orthonormal basis {$e_1..e_n$} Ricci curvature is

$$Ric(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} g(R(e_j,x)y,e_j)$$

And scalar curvature is
$$\tau(p)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} Ric(e_j,e_j)$$
For example, Riemannian metric $g$ on torus is given with $ds^2=dx^2+(3+\cos(x))^2dy^2$.
After calculating Christoffel symbols I have: $\Gamma_{12}^{2}=- \frac{\sin(x)}{3+\cos(x)}$, $\Gamma_{22}^{1}=\sin(x)(3+\cos(x))$ and others are zero.

Calculating gives: $$R(e_1,e_1)=g(\frac{\cos(x)}{3+\cos(x)}e_1,e_1)$$
$$R(e_2,e_2)=g(\cos(x)(3+\cos(x))e_2,e_2)$$ and for orthonormal basis $g(e_j,e_j)=1$ so

$$\tau(p)=R(e_1,e_1)+R(e_2,e_2)=\frac{\cos(x)}{3+\cos(x)}+\cos(x)(3+\cos(x))$$ and this have be twice as Gaussian curvature, but it isn't. It looks like term $\cos(x)(3+\cos(x))$ should be multipled with $g^{22}$ but why?

Comment: I haven't had time to check each step, so this may be unhelpful, but this kind of thing sometimes happens when you've assumed something is unit length when it isn't. E.g. $e_i$ are orthonormal, but the coordinate frame isn't.

Comment: Basically the scalar curvature is the contraction of the Ricci tensor, but to contract you must have 1 up and 1 down index, which is not clear in this presentation, but if you have two down indices, applying the inverse metric would raise one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Ricci tensor is correctly computed. However, you've computed your scalar curvature wrongly since your definition of scalar curvature lacks the inverse of the metric (note that the basis that you are trying to compute your scalar curvature on is not orthonormal but just orthogonal). More accurately, in matrix format, the scalar curvature is

$$S = \mathrm{tr}\left(\mathbf{I}^{-1}\,\mathrm{Ricci}\right).$$

which each of the above matrices is computed as follows

$$\mathrm{Ricci} = \left[ \begin {array}{cc} {\frac {\cos \left( x \right) }{3+
\cos \left( x \right) }}&0\\ 0& \left( 3+\cos
 \left(x \right)  \right) \cos \left( x \right) 
\end {array} \right],\quad\quad
\mathbf{I}^{-1} = \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0& \left( 3+\cos
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{-2}\end {array} \right]
$$
Now, calculating their multiplication according to the first formula gives
$${\frac {2\cos \left( x \right) }{3+\cos \left( x \right) }}$$
which is exactly two times the Gaussian curvature ${\frac {\cos \left( x \right) }{3+\cos \left( x \right) }}$.

Comment: Actually, his definition is correct (since in an orthonormal basis $g$ is just the identity). His mistake was that the basis he was using to calculate was *not* orthonormal.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade you are right. I edit the first line accordingly.